# My Cursor.moveToFirst always returns false

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm doing a select on my database and the cursor.moveToFirst always returns false,
I already looked for an answer and nothing.
That's my database function

```
public List<Obra> buscarListaMapa(String tipoGeoReferenciamentoFiltro, String idJurisdicionadoFiltro) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + BancoDadosHelper.TABELA_OBRA + " WHERE "+ BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_ID_TIPO_GEOREFENCIAMENTO + " = '"+tipoGeoReferenciamentoFiltro+"' and "+
                BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_ID_JURISDICIONADO+" = '"+idJurisdicionadoFiltro+"'", null);


        List<Obra> listaMapa = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String numObra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_NUM_OBRA));
                String descObra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_DESCRICAO_OBRA));
                String geoReferenciamento = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_GEOREFERENCIAMENTO));
                String tipoObra = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_TIPO_OBRA));
                Obra novaObra = new Obra(numObra, descObra, tipoObra, geoReferenciamento);
                listaMapa.add(novaObra);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return listaMapa;
    }
```

and when I did the same selection on the database WORKBENCH and My results were

Results of the Workbench doing the same select

[image]

Comment: is this code written in DBHandler class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper....?

Comment: Yes, but I already found the mistake, I was using a different tables, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add null condition check for the cursor to insure your cursor have some data.

```
 if(cursor!=null{
 cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String numObra = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_NUM_OBRA));
                String descObra = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_DESCRICAO_OBRA));
                String geoReferenciamento = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_GEOREFERENCIAMENTO 
 ));
                String tipoObra = 
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BancoDadosHelper.COLUNA_TIPO_OBRA));
                Obra novaObra = new Obra(numObra, descObra, tipoObra, 
 geoReferenciamento);
                listaMapa.add(novaObra);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


 }
```

Comment: I'm getting into IF statement but cursor.moveToFirst still returns false